# Glassfish instead of WebLogic for Oracle Forms 11g application

Tags: oracle, glassfish, weblogic, oracle11g, oracleforms

Is it possible to use Glassfish instead of WebLogic for Oracle Forms 11g application? Is there any container/plugin/whatever for Glassfish to use with Oracle Forms 11g?

Both Glassfish and WebLogic are J2EE servers, so...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle 11g applications are not certified on GlassFish Server, so you definitely would not have a supported configuration, and I highly doubt it would technically work without some porting effort by Oracle.

For example, no JRF layer exists for [GlassFish](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/core.1111/e10105/scaling.htm#BABHGGAC).